# email AJAX POST to web api

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-web-api, fiddler

I have client side function such as:

```
        var sendEmail = function (msgData) {
            jQuery.support.cors = true;
            var test = msgData;
            $.ajax({
                url         : "Api/EmailData/Send/{}",
                type        : "POST",
                data        : JSON.stringify(msgData),
                contentType : "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success     : function (data) {

                },
                error: function (error) {

                }
            });
    };
```

Web controller method like so:

```
        [Route("Api/EmailData/Send/{clientEmail}"), HttpPost]
        public HttpResponseMessage ContactUs(string clientEmail)
        {
            EmailBody emailbody = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<EmailBody>    (clientEmail);

            var result = MyDataRepository.ContactUs(emailbody);
            return Request.CreateResponse(result == false ?     HttpStatusCode.ExpectationFailed : HttpStatusCode.OK);
        }
```

My data matches the email class expected I have checked. However i still get a 404 not found. If i run in FIDDLER i get a Response Status as 204 No Content.I also include in my Fiddler header:

> Content-type:application/json

How can i make it work both from my JS client side and fiddler. Any pointers appreciated. Note i have included "Allow-Access-Control-Origin" for my Client on the Data Site in IIS. I have also tried removing JSON.stringify from my JS Client as suggested somewhere esle. Not sure what I am missing. Any help. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you may have a malformed url.  If my suspicions are correct the "/{}" at the end of url may be the source of your problems.

Here the {} are fine as you are declaring this on api controller end

```
    [Route("api/stuff/data/{id:int}")]
    public Data GetDataById(int id)
    {
        // your code here

        return data;
    }
```

But in your ajax call just pass the url without the curly braces

```
       $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "Api/EmailData/Send",
            data: JSON.stringify(actionData),
            traditional: true,
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (data) { },
            error: function (e) {  }
        });
```

Comment: u mean from Fiddler i should pass a parameter?

Comment: What I mean is that you are trying to pass data and from my experience you don't need the extra brackets there at the end.  That should all be handled on the server end.

Comment: Try my edit out and let me know if that fixes the issue

Comment: Thanks. Yes i removed the curley braces and now I can see my input data in fiddler. But I am still getting 404

Comment: If you are getting a Status 404 Error, that means your communication with the server is good but you have a bad URI.  This link has a list of all codes and their meanings [error codes](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html)

Comment: yes yes that's true. I was also missing the mailsettings in my config. Once I added that tag, fiddler could now talk to my api and send mail. However I am still getting a 404. I suspect it's an IIS related issue. I have two sites, one for data and the front-end